# EF Core. Skip & Take (Include)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Всем привет. Есть модель MainCategory, содержащая коллекцию Categories.
Можно ли "обрезать" их при вызове Include?

```
var mainCategory = _context.MainCategories.Include(c => c.Categories)
            .Skip(0).Take(3);
```

Мой код не работает. Отображаются все категории. Не могу понять, что делаю неправильно.

Мне нужно обрезать не mainCategory, а категории, которые она включает в себя.

Comment: хз сработает или нет, но `_context.MainCategories.Include(c => c.Categories.Skip(0).Take(3));` ?

Comment: Я пробовал такой вариант. Ошибка SQL-запроса.

Comment: какая именно ошибка?

Comment: вот это может помочь https://entityframework.net/include-with-where-clause

Comment: Посмотрел пример. Но там реализация с помощью даты. В таком случае, мне нужно по другому параметру. Как я могу узнать индекс элемента в таблице?

Comment: вам не надо индекс, там фильрация выглядитк как `something.Where(....)`, вам надо это звменить на `something.Skip(0).Take(3)`

Comment: Пробовал. Не сработало. Все равно считывает все категории.

Comment: вы пробовали код из вопроса или из ответа по той ссылке?

Comment: `var mainCategory = _context.MainCategories
                .Include(c => c.Categories)
                .Skip(0).Take(3).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: это код из вопроса, вам нужно пробовать код из ответов

Comment: `var mainCategory = _context.MainCategories
                .Where(m => m.Id == id)
                .Include(c => c.Categories)
                .Skip(0).Take(1)
                .FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92034/discussion-between-general2001-and-tym32167).

Comment: в чат не могу, у меня чат забанен. Почитайте внимательно что там есть по ссылке, там код отличается от того, что вы пробуете

Comment: OK. Спасибо за помощь.